# Tiles not working?

Tags: struts

I have created a login page which authenticates a user via the atuthentication class. After authentication I am using the following statement is to redirect to a JSP page.

```
response.sendRedirect("welcome.page");
```

This should look for the `tiles-defs.xml` for the mapping to an actual jsp page. I have provided this as follows

```
<definition name="main.layout" path="/mainLayout.jsp">
<put name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
<put name="info" value="/info.jsp"/>
<put name="menu" value="/menu.jsp"/>
<put name="body" value=""/>
<put name="footer" value="/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="welcome.page" extends="main.layout">
<put name="title" value="Welcome"/>
<put name="body" value="/welcome.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

I have created the `mainLayout.jsp` and the `welcome.jsp` pages. Now when a user has been authenticated it must redirect to `welcome.jsp`. But I am getting a **"The webpage cannot be found"** error. I guess the mapping is not correct which is why it is not able to find `welcome.jsp`, but I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect to a tile definition. A redirect consists in sending a response to the browser telling him: "please go to the following URL". A tile definition is not a URL.

You can redirect to a JSP, and the JSP will be executed. It's bad practice though, because in a properly designed MVC application, all the requests should go through a controller. And you can redirect to the URL of an action of course, which is what you should do: redirected to the `welcome.do` URL (assuming `welcome.do` is the URL of the Struts welcome action)

Comment: What i want is that after authentication I should be redirected to a welcome page, which is part of a tile structure. How do i do that?

Comment: Exactly as I said in my answer. You configure a Struts welcome action, which forwards to the welcome.page tile definition, and from the login action, you redirect to the URL of the welcome action.

Comment: what is a welcome action, is it an action mapping in struts-config.xml?

Comment: It's a Struts action (which is of course configured in the struts-config.xml, like all struts actions), that you name "welcome", since its goal is to welcome the visitor of your webapp. You may of course name it anyway you like.

Comment: I also tried using the mapping.findForward method from my loginAction class. I used the following   <global-forwards> <forward name="welcomepp" path="/welcome.page"/> </global-forwards>. But again i got the same page not found error. Is this the proper way to redirect?

Comment: Re-read my answer, and try to understand it. A redirect to a tile definition doesn't make any sense, whatever the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 1):

in one of the `ActionClass` you placed your user authenticate logic na, 
After authenticates the user Action class should return `return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);`
na, then the control focus in `struts-config.xml` file in that 
you should place code like this

```
 <action input="/index.jsp" name="loginForm" path="/login" scope="session" type="gg.locinAction">
        <forward name="success" path="welcome.page"/>
 </action>
```

then control focus on `tiles-defs.xml` for `welcome.page` definition in `tiles-defs.xml` file you should write definition like this

```
<definition name="welcome.page" extends="main.layout">
  <put name="title" value="Welcome"/>
  <put name="body" value="/welcome.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

then definition will be executed and your required page will be display on the tiles..